# What information should I include / not include in my posts?

Tags: discussion, best-practices, security

Is there any information other than a password that would be considered a security threat?

I am primarily interested in knowing what could compromise the security of a server, rather than the security of intellectual property.

For example, it seems to me that it would be a security threat to include both my username and domain name.

If I post a large amount of output, it is not possible for me to know what nefarious uses it could be put to, especially if data were combined from across multiple posts.

EDIT:
Based on suggestions in comments below, I have moved this question to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/202693/60508).

EDIT2: 
Moderators at ServerFault migrated it to [meta.serverfault](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/60508) ... but is that any better than here?

Comment: Hm, this is actually a question about technology, even though you asked it because you wanted to be a better SO question-asker. Belongs on one of the technical sites, I'm not 100% sure which one.

Comment: Based on Line 2 it belongs on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com)?

Comment: please don't write "[closed]" in your titles; that phrase has a very specific meaning on Stack Exchange sites, and your question is not actually closed yet.

Comment: @Popular Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

You should include enough relevant information in the post to enable people to answer your question.  You should exclude all irrelevant information.  The hard part is knowing what's relevant and what's not.  You can typically disguise user names and passwords (posting 'password' as the password is fine - assuming that isn't actually the password you really use); you can use example.com as the domain name (it is reserved by the IETF for that purpose).  You should hide names of organizations and people hidden in paths and URLs if there's the slightest sensitivity about them.

As to the meta-meta-question of where this question belongs - I really don't see why it doesn't belong on meta.stackoverflow.com.  The principles are much the same regardless; it is a perfectly good question.

It is getting far too hard to find 'the right site™' to post questions.